# Save date with user_save

Tags: drupal, date, profile

Can anyone tell me how to save a user´s birth date with user_save? I have day, month and year separatedly.

Comment: I could solve doing this

    $fechanacimiento['year']=(string)(int) $anio;
    $fechanacimiento['month']=(string)(int) $mes;
    $fechanacimiento['day']=(string)(int) $dia;
    ...
    $fields = array(
    ...
        'profile_fechanacimiento' => $fechanacimiento,
    ...
    }
    user_save('', $fields);

('fechanacimiento' means birth date).

Answer (score 0):

what version of drupal are you using? Mentioning Dru version helps to give you better explanations.

anyway, as first you should create Date of Birth field via profile module (it allows to add custom fields to user profiles), and then pass this field to user_save in second argument. See more http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/6
or http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/ for Drupal 7.

Regards